# Copy state array and keep initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to copy a state array to a variable to keep the initial value. The problem is that the state array value changes depending on if you are deleting or adding items to it.

In the code below I want to be able to search through a list, so when we have a match it will push that item to the favorites state. When i erase the input text to only contain an empty string I want to render out the unfiltered list.

I understand why this does not work but I don't know how to approach it.

Thank you!

```
let filteredArr = [];

const allFavorites = favorites.slice();

  favorites.filter(contact => {
    if (regExp.test(contact.name.toLowerCase()) && inputValue !== '') {
      filteredArr.push(contact);
    }
  });

  if (inputValue === '') {
    setFavorites(allFavorites);
  } else {
    setFavorites(filteredArr);
  }
```

Comment: please post your setFavorite() function.

Comment: it's just a setState with hooks. But i managed to solved it by pushing the filtered items to another array so i can maintain allFavorites in it's initial array

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
  const filteredArr = favorites.filter(contact => regExp.test(contact.name.toLowerCase()) && inputValue !== '');

  if (inputValue === '') {
    setFavorites([...favorites]);
  } else {
    setFavorites([...filteredArr]);
  }
```